# How to simulate pressing a custom keyboard key

Tags: c#, .net, windows, keypress

I have an extended keyboard and I want to simulate the key press of a special key that switches the keyboard mode. For that I think I need to find out key code, but can't figure out how can I get it. It's an extra key on my keyboard, not part of the `ConsoleKey` `enum`, and the only functions I've found to catch keys work with this `enum`.

Comment: Which key are you referring to when you say *"special key"*? Is it a combination of keys, or a single key?

Comment: @RufusL single key. It's extra key that isn't present on normal keyboards

Comment: Then it might not be a key but a switch that is just local/isolated to the keyboard  and not available to the PC Can you give more details on the key? Brand/model keyboard etc.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd it's SuperPower EZ 7000, here is photo https://keddr.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Codegen-SuperPower-EZ-7000.jpg the one I need is to the right upper corner from Esc

Comment: What does the button normally do?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd  switching modes of keyboard that keys like F1-F12 change their behavior

Answer (score 1):

If the key does something like change the keyboard color, this will depend on whether or not there is software on the computer which can do so as well.  If not, this is probably just a local switch to the keyboard and that key isn't on the keymap for the keyboard itself, ether.

If it changes something else, it will depend on if there is driver software for the device or if it uses a default Windows driver.
If it takes installed software, it's probably a custom event (like some joysticks have) and would only be found if you use a reference to a library distributed by the keyboard manufacturer. 
If it does not, then the switching mode is probably a "remap" mode tied to the keyboard firmware, and just changes which `KeyDown` event the affected keys send.  If this is true, there is no way for Windows to even see what setting the keyboard is on.

Comment: This key doesn't need any drivers to be installed, what it do is switching modes of keyboard that keys like F1-F12 change their behavior

Answer (score 0):

I would say the logic for the function key changes is on the keyboard itself. For instance, the `Fn` key on my laptop does not cast any keyboard events by itself, but when combined with *certain* other keys, a key code is sent to the OS with a key code that triggers certain functionality.

For instance, in my keyboard `Fn + Left` lowers the volume, but the virtual key sent to the OS is `VK_VOLUME_DOWN` (see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx) for a list of virtual keys.)

Good news is, you can test the keys individually to see which key codes get sent to the OS! To accomplish this, you might want to set up a [low-level keyboard hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985(v=vs.85).aspx)) using P/Invokes.

There's a [tutorial on CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook) that may be useful to you.